# Angular - Cannot concatenate values in HTML page

Tags: html, angular, interpolation

In our Angular project, we use interpolation as shown below, but we also need to use this interpolated value in the [state] property. But we haev not managed so far. Any idea?

If we set id values as shown below, there is no problem.

```
<a routerLink="/ticket/details/" [state]="{ id: '5' }" >{{row.TicketId}}</a>
```

But we cannot get dynamically by obtaining row.TicketId (it is obtained as label in {{row.TicketId}}) but cannot concatenate with id parameter.

```
<a routerLink="/ticket/details/" [state]="{ id: {{row.TicketId}} }" >{{row.TicketId}}</a>
```

Comment: Did you tried `[state]="{ id: row.TicketId }"`?

Comment: @PatrykUszyński put it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brackets in `[state]="..."` tell Angular to evaluate the template expression, so you cant use interpolation there. So, as I said in comment it should be:

```
[state]="{ id: row.TicketId }"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try  [state]="{ id: row.TicketId }"
```